# jQuery Detect When One Image Has Loaded - Without Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, is there a way to detect when one particular image is done loading? I've seen this plugin: http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/ but this should be a simple solution. I really don't want to download another plugin.

User clicks on this element:

```
<input type="file" />
```

jQuery function places the image into this element:

```
<img src="" />
```

I want to determine when the image has finished loading. Can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: Use `<img onload='' />`?

Comment: @kei just tried the equivalent in jquery: `$('img').load(function(){})`. Didn't fire.

Comment: Try `$('img').on('load',function(){})` instead. Might be worth a try.

Comment: @kei Nope. From [The official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) seems to say that `load` is for detecting the load of the first image as the page is loading. Unless I misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle with a **really rough** working example of .load() working [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/aTfAu/).

**HTML**

```
<figure class="button">button</figure>
<div id="imgload"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

#imgload {display:none;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('#imgload').html('<img src="http://placekitten.com/700/400"/>');

    $('#imgload img').load(function(){
        $('#imgload').fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

On click, the image is placed in the div and then after it finishes loading, the div fades in. So it successfully detects when the image has finished loading. I've used this technique a hundred times.

EDIT: cleaned it up a little bit

Comment: hmm... that seems to do what I want it to do. Lemme give that a try. I didn't think of placing it inside the `click` event callback.